# How to have Gracie visit your town in Animal Crossing: New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How can you have Gracie visit your town in Animal Crossing: New Leaf?

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the second best store.

from [Gracie's page on the wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Gracie):

> After the player has expanded the Nookling store in their town to  T.I.Y., Gracie will start to visit the town's Plaza on completely random days. However, Gracie may rarely appear for some Players, making it more difficult to get the T&T Emporium.

In order to get T.I.Y.:

> To upgrade to T.I.Y., the player must spend a total of 50,000 Bells in Super T&T and 21 days have passed since the opening of the store.

[Also from the wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/T.I.Y.).

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade Super T&T into TIY. To do this, at least 50,000 Bells have to be spent at the store and TIY has to be in the town for at least 21 days. Also Gracie visits the town plaza on random days.

[More here](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Gracie)

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too. I have only had her once this month. What I do is stock up on clothes because that way she will usually come quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to spend 50,000 bells to upgrade the Super T&T (i just upgraded mine) and you have to have the Super T&T for 21 days.